# Working beyond Max Value (Java)

Tags: java

I have a problem that requires me to go well beyond the Max Value of Integers in Java. How can I have an exception so that Java will let me do this, or get around these rules of Java?

Comment: Use Long ... this will do it

Comment: Use long and go save the world.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't known of the Value before. Sucks that I got downvoted but considering that is right there in Java, yea I'd downvote myself.

Comment: @Maddoga yeah, that's a newbie question, and stackoverflow is notoriously abrasive with these kind of questions (arguably for good reasons). Still, your newfound knowledge is worth more than those few virtual reputation points lost :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `long` value or `Long` wrapper.

When you've reached `Long.MAX_VALUE` then use `BigInteger`, which has a very large capacity, at least from `-2^Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `2^Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Come back for additional tips when `BigInteger` is no longer enough.

Comment: _And when you have reach the limit of BigInteger, just upgrade your RAM!_

Comment: @AxelH And when you have bought all RAMs in the world?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I will answer to that if you find me a "number" that will need that much byte ;)

Comment: @AxelH: *Ramsey theory* has a lot of such numbers, the most famous is, probably, a *Graham's number*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number

Comment: @AxelH "BigInteger must support values in the range -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) and may support values outside of that range." from the javadoc

Comment: @Aaron, you are a killjoy ;)